# Python - Make more visible the plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a figure, this figure has big number and small number so I made a simple example for that. The problem is the end of the plot is not visible so that it is not good in the report. The picture is not clear after 100 value so How can I do more visible if data are so small?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
b1=[2000,1800,1750,100,90,80,70,75,80,70,74,60,20,15,12,12,14,14,14,14,12,11,12,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.6]
b2=[2000,1800,1750,100,90,80,70,75,80,70,74,60,20,15,12,12,14,14,14,14,12,11,12,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.7,5]
b3=[2000,1800,1750,100,90,80,70,75,80,70,74,60,20,15,12,12,14,14,14,14,12,11,12,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.7,54]
c=[0,3]

scaled_a = np.interp(a, (min(a), max(a)), c)
print(scaled_a)

plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot(scaled_a,b1,'r')
plt.annotate('%0.2f' % b1[-1], xy=(1, b1[-1]), xytext=(8, 0), 
         xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), textcoords='offset 
points')
plt.subplot(312)
plt.plot(scaled_a,b2,'b')
plt.annotate('%0.2f' % b2[-1], xy=(1, b2[-1]), xytext=(8, 0), 
         xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), textcoords='offset points')
plt.subplot(313)
plt.plot(scaled_a,b3,'g')
plt.annotate('%0.2f' % b3[-1], xy=(1, b3[-1]), xytext=(8, 0), 
         xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), textcoords='offset points')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Use a logarithmic scaling? As shown in many other questions around? Maybe?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited the photo `plt.yscale('log'), plt.grid() ` But if there are two signal in the graph so it does not easily distinguish between signals. Because the signals are so close to each other.

Comment: Yes. So the conclusion would be that your data is quite similar, right? What's the conclusion of your report? What message do you want to convey by showing those data?

Comment: I am doing the Kalman Filter so that state and covariance estimation are almost same in some situation but I want to see the differences in the plot. If the people see the plot, state estimation should be under the covariance estimation so that if data are about 100, these are not visible to see.

Comment: In such case I would plot all three curves into the same plot. You may also show a plot with the global curve and one which zooms into the small range. One could also show a plot of the difference instead of the absolute values. I guess you have to know for yourself what's best showing your data. If the question is then how to produce a plot that shows what you desire, Stackoverflow may be a good place to ask for help.

Comment: Thank you :) log scale is better with real data thanks ;)